# How to setup Ethernet connected computer as gateway

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, ethernet, raspberry-pi

I am trying to re-create a setup I had previously before formatting & re-install and I do not remember exactly what I did.

So my current setup is as follows:

- ADSL/router+wifi as gateway 192.168.1.1 where all computers that connect via ethernet or wifi get internet access
- raspberry pi connected via ethernet (ip: 192.168.1.100) in ADSL router and also to remote VPN provider via tun0 connection  (subnet 10.x.x.x)

What I (somehow) did before is I had setup the raspberry pi as an alternative gateway. So I could go to a client (that was connected to ADSL router) and change the gateway from the original 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.100 and all the traffic of that client would go via VPN (so it would use the public IPV4 address of the VPN server) via the pi.

I cannot remember how I setup things before, but now simply choosing the gateway on the client as 192.168.1.100 wont route anything outside (so no internet connection to the client).

Can anyone give me some advice how to set this thing up?

Many thanks

P.S.
I dont want to use the wifi on the pi at all

The routing table on the pi looks like this (and the PI has internet access):

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.10.8.53      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         fritz.box       0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
10.10.8.1       10.10.8.53      255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.10.8.53      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
li1426-184.memb fritz.box       255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
```

Comment: Which operating system for the client ?

Comment: all Linux-variants (Raspian, Ubuntu, Debian etc....). Multiple clients

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anyone give me some advice how to set this thing up?

Look at `tcpdump -n -i <interface>` to determine what is or isn't **currently** happening. Do the packets from LAN devices reach your Pi at all? Does the Pi attempt to send them out through the VPN interface? Does the VPN client send anything at all to the VPN server? Does the Pi receive anything *back*? What to set up or un-set up depends on what's missing.

> I cannot remember how I setup things before, but now simply choosing the gateway on the client as 192.168.1.100 wont route anything outside (so no internet connection to the client).

Make sure routing is *enabled* on the gateway (through `sysctl`), then make sure its firewall 'forward' rules allow packets to go through.

With most VPN connections, routing is not quite enough. It might be that the Pi already *does* route packets, if you actually look at your network interfaces using `tcpdump`, but they do not produce any replies – because the VPN server has no idea about the addressing on the LAN side of your gateway and can't reply to 192.168.1.x (and probably outright drops packets from those addresses).

If that's the case, you'll also need DNAT or masquerading, so that IP addresses of your LAN devices would be rewritten to use the gateway's own VPN IP address. It's the same `MASQUERADE` or `DNAT` iptables (or nftables) rule as documented elsewhere.

Comment: ah....what was missing was this:

`sudo iptables -t nat -s 192.168.1.0/24 -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE`

on the PI


ipv4 forwarding was already enabled
`net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`

Answer (score 0):

For a temporary change, use commands like :

```
sudo route delete default gw 192.168.1.1 eth0
sudo route add default gw 192.168.1.100 eth0
```

For a permanent change :

- Edit the file `/etc/network/interfaces`
- Find the section for the adapter you want to change, usually `eth0`
  for wired
- Add the gateway IP address, for example, `gateway 192.168.1.100`
- Save your changes
- Restart the network by `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`.

Comment: this is on the client(s) side right?
I did the second option already (on network/interface) but I am not getting any access to the internet

Comment: Yes, this is for the client. If it doesn't work the problem is probably with the Pi setup or the VPN.

Comment: Yes probably the pi. I updated the routing table if this helps

Comment: See if [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-22-04) is useful, although it might be too detailed.